# Frequently-updated satellite images of Amazonia/Brazil

Tags: images, brazil

I want to do time analysis of satellite images from the Amazonia/Brazil. I'm looking mainly for optical images. Ideally, such dataset would be frequently updated (every month or week). I don't need the finest resolution since I'm looking for <~square-kilometer features, resolutions in the decameter~hectometer range would be enough.

Then the question is: is there any frequently updated/released, open image set to explore online?

Comment: There are probably quite a few datasets that will fit your use case.  You can try browsing LANDSAT products from [USGS Earth Explorer](https://earthexplorer.usgs.gov/) or [NASA's Earthdata Search](https://search.earthdata.nasa.gov/).  Also see some of the answers to [this post](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/985/7031).

Comment: Maybe you can use some images from the ESA Sentinel missions?
https://sentinel.esa.int/web/sentinel/about-sentinel-online

Comment: If this is something you are not finding any, may I suggest you perhaps contact ESRI office in Brazil about it ? They may help you to lead where they might know how to find what you are looking for... https://www.esri.com/en-us/contact#c=br&t=0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some links from government agencies:

http://www.inmet.gov.br/satelites

http://www.dgi.inpe.br/catalogo/

http://www.dgi.inpe.br/CDSR/

https://www.redemet.aer.mil.br/?i=produtos&p=imagens-de-satelite